# Stop Suite Execution After First Failure In TestNG

Tags: ant, testng

I am using Ant to execute a set of TestNG tests as follows:

```
 <testng suitename="functional_test_suite" outputdir="${basedir}/target/"
classpathref="maven.test.classpath" dumpCommand="false" verbose="2"
haltonfailure="true" haltonskipped="false" parallel="methods" threadCount="2">
   <classfileset dir="${basedir}/target/test-classes/">
    <include name="**/*Test.class" />
   </classfileset>
```

I would like for the tests to stop immediately after the first failure. haltonfailure does not seem to do the trick, it just halts the ant build if the whole suite has test failures. Is there any way I can halt the suite execution on first failure?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you figure your issue out... I haven't used TestNG before, but I have experienced something similar on Selenium(JUnit) tests. There is one type of assertion that collects failures only to display them at the end of the test, and another that halts the test immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can set dependencies on your individual test methods. [testng dependencies](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods). This will only run test methods if desired dependencies passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a suite listener for this purpose.

```
public class SuiteListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
    private boolean hasFailures = false;

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (hasFailures) {
                throw new SkipException("Skipping this test");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        if (method.isTestMethod() && !testResult.isSuccess()) {
            synchronized (this) {
                hasFailures = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Listeners(SuiteListener.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 2);  // Fail test
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        // This test will be skipped
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```